# The denoiser doesn't work on my render

Tags: rendering, denoise

I tried to do a render but i noticed the denoiser isn't applied. Well at least to the donut. I'm not sure if it worked on my icing.

[image]

[image]

I tried to un-check the denoiser and re-check it but it didn't work. Unless i need to confirm my modifications? If so, how do i do it?

Comment: Did you press F12 to render the image again?

Comment: I'm on mac and pressing F12 make the noise louder. Noramlly you press fn + 12 but it opens the dashboard (basically it doesn't refresh). Is there another way to do it ?